# Ember-CLI rundown using it with Laravel or other backend frameworks

Tags: javascript, ember.js, laravel, laravel-4, ember-cli

Using the `ember-starter-kit` all I had to do was throw the contents of it in the `/my_laravel_app/public` folder and everything was fine.

Now I am trying to create a project with `laravel` and `ember-cli`

I'm a little confused as to how I need to structure my application? In which laravel folder should I be running the `ember new my-app` command? Furthermore, how can I use `apache` for testing my `ember-cli` application instead of using `ember server` command since I need to test it with my laravel generated apis.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here is one way to do it

Go into your root `laravel` folder and run the `ember new my_app_name`

Then go into your `my_app_name` folder and create a new file `build_custom.sh` add the following lines to the file

```
ember build
cp dist/index.html ../app/views/ember.php
cp -r dist/assets ../public/assets
```

Explanation: the first line builds your ember-cli app and generates all the necessary files in the `dist/` folder. The second line copies the `index.html` file generated to `app/views/` folder and renames it `ember.php` so laravel can recognize it. The last line just copies all the assets into your laravel public folder

You can add the following in your `app/routes.php` file in laravel to serve your ember app. Make sure it's all the way at the bottom so your other api routes take preference

```
Route::get('{ember?}', function() {
    return View::make('ember');
})->where('ember', '.*');
```

That should be it, everything should work as intended. Good luck.

Comment: I am still getting a `UnrecognizedURLError: /ember` when I navigate to `ember` route on my laravel app. This seems to be related to settings the rootUrl of the ember app.

Comment: this is not working for me. Nor the ember.php is created neither the assets are moved. Ant help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Nouphal.M did you try running $ bash build_custom.sh from the my-app-name directory?

Comment: Works like a charm. Just need to be careful that these two lines are copying the right files at the right places: 
`cp dist/index.html ../app/views/ember.php`
 & `cp -r dist/assets ../public/assets` In my case the assets were getting copied to `/public/assets/assets` folder. And Therefore was giving `UnrecognizedURLError: /ember`. Once I fixed the path. Everything worked fine

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it:

You can create two separate folders: `backend` *(laravel app)* and `frontend` *(ember app)*
. Let's say, your laravel app is running under `192.168.10.10`, you can then proxy your ember app ajax requests using ember-cli command: `ember serve --proxy http://192.168.10.10`. Using this proxy option, all commands will be passed to ip address, specified with --proxy option - in this case ip address, where laravel app is running (where api is listening).

Answer (score 0):

If you getting `UnrecognizedURLError: /ember` try to remove welcome route on laravel...